# How to find particular data with date array list in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this type of data for reference

```
{
    "_id": "62fe02deff92f90b7095ce86",
    "status": true,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "jobId": "60631e25835eacf5321e178a",
    "scheduleStartDate": "2021-03-10T12:51:13.000Z",
    "scheduleEndDate": "2021-03-1oT13:21:13.000Z",
    "round": "L1",
    "createdAt": "2021-03-10T12:51:18.535Z",
    "updatedAt":"2021-03-10T12:51:18.535Z",
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": "62fe02deff92f90b7095ce87",
    "status": true,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "jobId": "60643f89983fec5c29cb9950",
    "scheduleStartDate": "2021-03-12T12:51:13.000Z",
    "scheduleEndDate": "2021-03-12T13:21:13.000Z",
    "round": "L1",
    "createdAt": "2021-03-10T12:51:18.535Z",
    "updatedAt":"2021-03-10T12:51:18.535Z",
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": "62fe02deff92f90b7095ce87",
    "status": true,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "jobId": "60643f89983fec5c29cb9950",
    "scheduleStartDate": "2021-03-13T12:51:13.000Z",
    "scheduleEndDate": "2021-03-13T13:21:13.000Z",
    "round": "L1",
    "createdAt": "2021-03-10T12:51:18.535Z",
    "updatedAt":"2021-03-10T12:51:18.535Z",
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": "62fe02deff92f90b7095ce87",
    "status": true,
    "isDeleted": false,
    "jobId": "60643f89983fec5c29cb9950",
    "scheduleStartDate": "2021-03-14T12:51:13.000Z",
    "scheduleEndDate": "2021-03-14T13:21:13.000Z",
    "round": "L1",
    "createdAt": "2021-03-10T12:51:18.535Z",
    "updatedAt":"2021-03-10T12:51:18.535Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have first **filter data** using date range like this.
** First filter query like**

```
$match: {
       jobId: { $in: value.jobIds },
      scheduleStartDate: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate },
    }
```

So Its getting data list. After this list I need to add more **specific date** filter not range only specific date which is come from API request like

```
  "dates": [
        "11-03-2021",
        "12-03-2021",
        "13-03-2021",
        "14-03-2021"
    ],
```

So by using this I make query for filter which is use in **aggregation**  that specific data which I want. that query like

```
    if (value.dates) {
        value.dates = value.dates.map((date) => {
          return moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss");
        });
        filterArray.push({
          $match: {
            $and: {scheduleStartDate: value.dates},
          },
        });
      }
```

But I get empty result set because `$in` not match condition so what should I do for use specific date list.

**my aggregation query like**

```
const result = await slotModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      userId: { $in: value.userIds },
      scheduleStartDate: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "myjobs",
      localField: "jobId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "job",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: filterArray,
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      round: 1,
      type: 1,
      mode: 1,
      scheduleStartDate: 1,
      scheduleEndDate: 1,
      feedbackId: 1,
    },
  },
]);

return result;


Thanks' in advance.
```

Comment: What is start date, end date for the query yu used?

Comment: You compare `Date` values with **string**, this does not work. Try `return moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate()` in order to compare `Date` value with a `Date` value.